# $query->where plus AND operator

Tags: php, sql, joomla

From Joomla documentation i read of how to run sql queries in php.

My code is the below:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName('customfield_value'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_product_customfields'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('virtuemart_custom_id')." = ".$db->quote('322'));
$query->and($db->quoteName('virtuemart_product_id'). " = ".$item->virtuemart_product_id));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObject();

echo "Factory Code:" . $results->customfield_value;
```

Code was bringing a Factory code but not product's Factory code and then i had to add the line

$query->and......

to tell to bring Factory code from specific product but it brings no results at all. Eventually i write something wrong with $query->and ?

Any ideas/solutions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found correct answer/syntax:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName('customfield_value'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_product_customfields'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('virtuemart_custom_id')." = 322", "AND")
      ->where($db->quoteName('virtuemart_product_id')." = ". $item->virtuemart_product_id);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the AND but more important, you should explain your answer (such as there is no "and" method etc) and then you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Yes you are correct! I will keep that in mind!Thanks